# Verify user by Firebase ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When a user installs an application containing Firebase, multiple types of IDs are generated. For example, Firebase Installation ID and Firebase Messaging Token.

They are unique to the device and the Application.

**Question :**

Is there a way to verify that some ID is generated by the Application using Firebase Admin API?

**Notes :**
I saw that you can verify User IDs, but that is for Firebase Auth, users that are logged using one of the services. But I'm looking for an ID when the user hasn't yet logged into any service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no verification process for Firebase Installation IDs or FCM tokens.  The IDs are intentionally kept separate from any sense of "user ID" for privacy reasons.

You can find out if an FCM token is valid by attempting to send a message to it.  The FCM API will [generate an error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) if it's not valid (or became invalid for some reason).

Comment: By valid do you mean generated by Firebase, or generated by the same app?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Does it validate that the Token is a valid FCM token, regardless of who generated it, or will it validate that this FCM belongs to the Firebase Project?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  A token is a token.  It doesn't matter how it was generated - it just matters if it works.  If it works, then it was generated by the SDK.